# Dealing with $in using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is the code:

```
usermodel.findOne({ user: req.session.user }, function (err, user){

   usermodel.find({ _id: {$in: user.follow } }, { user: true }, function (err, users){

         usermodel.find({ author: { $in: users.user }}, function (err, images){

          console.log(users);
          console.log(images);


        });
     });
```

And this is the Schema:

var userschema = new mongoose.Schema({

```
  user: String,
  follow: [String],
  message: [{ 

              title: String,
              author: String,
              message: String

           }],

});
```

The `follow`array contains the `_id`s of the users that the actual user is following. With the first `usermodel.find` y get the `follow` array. With the second `usermodel.find`, I get the users names:

```
[ { _id: 50fd9c7b8e6a9d087d000006, user: 'Mrmangado' },
  { _id: 50fd9d3ce20da1dd7d000006, user: 'kirbo' } ]
```

And, with the third and last `usermodel.find`, I'm trying to get the message of the users. I get the users' names in the previous `usermodel.find`, and the `author` of the message has the same value of the user that has created it. The problem is the way I get the users' names, I think I have to have the users' names like this way:

```
[{ user: 'Mrmangado' },
 { user: 'kirbo' }]
```

If I receive an array like this, the `$in` statement will work perfectly. Is there any way to get an output like this...?

Thank's advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that's what you want?  The `author` field is a user's name, not its `_id`?  If so, you could just map the resulting object to get the name.

```
var usernames = users.map(function(u) { return u.user; });
//= ["Mrmangado", "kirbo"]
```